# Java Web Start getDocumentBase

Tags: java, url, jnlp, java-web-start

I am experimenting with Java Web Start.

I have just written a basic `JApplet` which has a method on the `Applet` class called `getDocumentBase()`.  This returns the full `URL` to the location the `Applet` is running (under Tomcat) i.e. http://myserver:8080/myapp/whateverapplet.jar.

However, I am looking for something similar with a web start application.  I need to know where it is running.  Is there anything that can give me this information?

**EDIT**

In terms of where it is running I mean if I run a web start from a JNLP file I want:

http://myserver:8080/myapp

If I run the JAR from a folder on the network I want:

\\server\myapp

Or if I run the JAR from a folder on my machine I want:

D:\myapp

**End Edit**

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to know where it is running."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to get the code base URL from within your running application? If this is the case, you can use this snippet:

```
final BasicService bs = (BasicService) ServiceManager.lookup(
    "javax.jnlp.BasicService");
final URL codeBase = bs.getCodeBase();
```

Note that you'll have to depend on the [JNLP API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/) to compile this code (for the `BasicService` class).

Comment: @Andrew - thanks for the example.  I've tried it in my code and it works fine from a web start.  Like I mentioned on the other answer by aioobe, I did try MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm() which gave me the full path to the JAR file however I wanted to know the location.

Comment: @Andez: "@Andrew - thanks for the example."  You're welcome, but ITYM 'Waldheinz' there.  ;)  I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [`javax.jnlp.BasicService.getCodeBase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html#getCodeBase%28%29) is what you're looking for.

> Returns the codebase for the application. The codebase is either specified directly in the JNLP file, or it is the location of the JAR file containing the main class of the application.
>   
>   **Returns:**
>        a URL with the codebase of the application

(The [`BasicService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/BasicService.html) "*mimics loosely the `AppletContext` functionality*" which provides the `getDocumentBase()` you're referring to.)

Comment: See also my little [demo. of the `BasicService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs).

Comment: @aioobe - thanks for that.  Thats works for me.  However, I did the following code which gives me the full path to the JAR file without using BasicService.  MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toExternalForm()

Comment: @Andez: If that code (presumably running in a trusted app.) provides the location of the class files in the local file system, don't write anything there, and don't expect to find anything there that is not already on the run-time class-path of the app.  Why **exactly** do you want this information?  What feature is it that knowing that location brings to the application?

Comment: @Andrew - we have an Images folder in the same location as our JAR file which the application will load at various points.  These are not contained in a resource file as the idea is to allow customisation on site without recompiling a JAR file.  new JButton( "Button 1", new ImageIcon( new URL(fullurl + "Images/add.png" ), "" ) ) works for me where fullurl is given by the URL.toString() from your example.

Comment: If by "onsite" you mean the site from which this version of the app. is launched, then `getCodeBase()` as mentioned by aioobe is the way to go.  If you mean "on the end user's desktop" then there is a better strategy to pursue (using the `PersistenceService`).

Comment: @Andrew - I've updated the question to make it a little clearer (I hope)